# Questions about Varnish file storage engine

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, varnish, disk-cache

I have Varnish cache in front of some websites with the following storage engine configuration:

- Storage: file
- Size: 130GB

The server where it is installed has the following configuration:

- RAM: 7.5 GB
- SSD 1: 15GB (System)
- SSD 2: 150GB (130GB for Varnish storage)
- CPU: 4

Summary, it is a c4.xlarge on AWS.

Currently, Varnish is currently using 123GB of the allocated storage (130GB).

So, what will happen when Varnish use all the 130GB of allocated storage?

- Is Varnish going to delete the storage.bin file and create a new one?
- Is it gonna stop working?
- Or what is going to happen?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Varnish is a cache.  It'll do what caches do.  Expire stuff.

Answer (score 1):

When the storage space is exhausted, Varnish won't create a new storage file or stop working. I will simply start evicting (i.e. 'nuking' using the Varnish terminology) objects cached in the storage when space for newer objects is required. You can check when that's happening looking at the `MAIN.n_lru_nuked` counter in `varnishstat`.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I am currently checking varnishstat.